# What is prototype in javascript mvc/oop structure

Tags: javascript, google-maps, javascript-objects, javascriptmvc

Can anybody tell me why we are using `.prototype.` while working with JavaScript?
I come to this when i was working with google map api.
In which(Just an example) we are using `google.maps.Marker.prototype.setPosition` while the class is `google.maps.Marker` only.

Comment: Take a look at the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: Javascript, while still object oriented, uses prototypical inheritance rather than the more common classical inheritance. Read up on the differences in the MDN docs linked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (adapted) Why are are we using google.maps.Marker.prototype.setPosition

In short, any object created with `new google.maps.Marker(/* params */)` will have access to the `setPosition` property defined there (unless it is overridden):

```
google.maps.Marker.prototype.setPosition = function() { return 42; }

var x = new google.maps.Marker();
x.setPosition(); // 42

var y = new google.maps.Marker();
y.setPosition(); // 42

x.setPosition = function() { return 'Overriden only for x'; };    
x.setPosition(); // Overriden only for x
y.setPosition(); // 42
```

The mechanics of it are explained on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). The gist of it is that `new` creates an object that inherits (via the prototype chain) from the constructor's `prototype` property.

Answer (score 2):

most programers familiar with c++ or java before they study javascript

so they want to use javascript as they do in java and c++ to simulate the four concept: static field of

class. static method of class. instance field of object, method of object

to simulate the method of object it is usually with prototype property of the constructor

```
function Book (name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Book.prototype.getName = function () {
  return this.name;
}

var b = new Book("javascript");

console.log(b.getName()); // javascript
```

http://jsfiddle.net/98yPb/ this is the demo

Answer (score 1):

We are using prototype when we have to change a property in the whole class (like static property in C++) instead of just in a single object.

Prototype is the way to access static properties and function of the class...